# Prove that if $\gcd(, ()) = 1$ and $a^m\equiv 1\pmod{n}$ then $a\equiv 1\pmod{n}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, totient-function

> Prove that if $$\gcd(, ()) = 1$$ and $$a^m\equiv 1\pmod{n}$$ then $$a\equiv 1\pmod{n}$$ given that 
>   $$\text{gcd}(a,n) = 1 \quad( a, n , m ∈ ℕ )$$

I know how to explain the opposite way but I didn't reach any conclusion about this one.

Please help, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\gcd(m,\varphi(n))=1$ then there are integers $x,y$ such that $mx+\varphi(n)y=1$. Now write $$a=a^{mx+\varphi(n)y}=(a^m)^x(a^{\varphi(n)})^y$$ and use $a^m\equiv 1\pmod{n}$ (hypothesis) and $a^{\varphi(n)}\equiv 1\pmod{n}$ (Euler's theorem).

Comment: On what basis did you assume that $a=(a^m)^x(a^φ(n))^y$ is equal?

Comment: @John: Edited, now it should be clear.